# Performance opening and closing connection vs commandTimeout

Tags: c#, mysql, performance, timeoutexception

I'm using `Mysql 5.6.4`. `c# 4`.

Case 1. Just say I setted `commandTimeout = 300`(5 minutes)  and executed in 1 go. and then `close` the `connection`.

Case 2. I setted `commandTimeout = 150`(2.5 minutes) and iterated the same procedure **two times**(retry count) **if timeout exception caught in MySqlException**.

So my question is that which one will **perform better**.

Comment: What factors cause it to work on a second attempt but not the first?

Comment: Just say I'm updating millions record in one table and timeout came(`CommandTimeout`). so I want to try one more time. so what is better to open for a long time or open for small time and increase retry count(keeping it as configurable in web config)

Comment: If you get a timeout exception, more likely that it will timeout again. Executing the query again isn't going to help(in most cases). You need to optimize your query instead.

Comment: No @SriramSakthivel. Due to `CommandTimeout` that is showing timeout exception. Not in Sql query is timing out. Its Simple Update statement.

Comment: Yes, but when you call the stored procedure for second time, what is the difference? if you have the same timeout, again it will timeout right?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel It may or may not. I just want to know which is better way ? What is better Opening a connection for a long time or opening and closing multiple time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither.

Connect/disconnect time is very small.  The "right" way to code is to connect, do everything you need to do, then disconnect.

If you have a command that is taking "too long", then rethink the command or increase the relevant timeout.

UPDATEing a million rows as a standard task *usually* implies a poorly designed schema and data-flow.  Let's hear the rationale for it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are allowing [Connection Pooling](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-connection-pooling.html) to do its job, then you should always be better off opening a connection and then closing it immediately.  Pooling should erase most of the overhead of opening the second time.